# Compare date between 2 date ranges

Tags: linux, bash, datetime, jq

I'm trying to compare date between 2 date ranges

```
currentdate= curl -s "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Jerusalem" | jq . | jq '.utc_datetime'

if [ "$currentdate" -ge "2020-10-28T10:00:00:00" && "$currentdate" -le "2020-11-10T10:00:00:00"]
then echo "between 10 days range dates"

fi
echo "not between 10 days range dates"
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to get current date to compare:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The needlessly complex way
curdate=$(
  date -d "$(
    curl -s "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Jerusalem" |
      jq -j .utc_datetime
  )" +%s
)

# The shorter, but still POSIX shell way
curdate=$(date +%s)

# The most efficient Bash 4.2+ way
printf -v curdate '%(%s)T'

#mindate=$(date -d "2020-10-28T10:00:00" +%s)
mindate=1603875600

#maxdate=$(date -d "(@$mindate) + 10 days" +%s)
maxdate=1603929600


if [ $curdate -ge $mindate ] && [ $curdate -le $maxdate ]
then 
     echo "between 10 days range dates"
else
     echo "not between 10 days range dates"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`-ge` and `-le` are *numeric* comparison operators. Since you're using that ISO date format, you can compare the dates as strings:

```sh
date1="2020-10-28T10:00:00:00"
date2="2020-11-10T10:00:00:00"
if [[ "$date1" <= "$currentdate" && "$currentdate" <= "$date2" ]]; ...
```

Comment: Would work with occidental Left-To-Rigth locales and collation, but may as well fail with Right-To-Left and differently collated locales.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing in jq if you want.

```
begin_date="2020-10-28T10:00:00Z"
end_date="2020-11-10T10:00:00Z"
curl -s "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Jerusalem" | \
jq --arg bd $begin_date --arg ed $end_date '.unixtime 
   | if . >= ($bd | fromdate) and . <= ($ed | fromdate) 
     then "between 10 days range dates"
     else "not between 10 days range dates"
     end'
```

`fromdate` converts the beginning and end dates into the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). We can compare those numbers with the value of .unixtime.

I altered the beginning and end dates to a format that jq could easily recognize.

Note: in your original program, you only need to invoke jq once: `jq '.utc_datetime'` would work.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to format the dates into "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" for this. So first format the date by only taking the first 19 characters and then running that through date with -d and formatting with %s

```
currentdate=$(curl -s "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Jerusalem" | jq . | jq '.utc_datetime')

if [[ "$(date -d ${currentdate:1:19} +%s)" -ge "$(date -d "2020-10-28T10:00:00" +%s)" && "$(date -d ${currentdate:1:19} +%s)" -le "$(date -d "2020-10-28T10:00:00" +%s)" ]]
then 
     echo "between 10 days range dates"
else
     echo "not between 10 days range dates"
fi
```